# HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity Error when sending data to LoopBack from Java client

Tags: java, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am doing an HttpPost to send data to LoopBack and get the response. I am getting an error as below from LoopBack :

HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity [X-Powered-By: Express, Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 1528, Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 18:13:45 GMT, Connection: keep-alive]

So, what I did in java is created a json from a java object , when I used this JSON in loopback api explorer, the data was inserted and gave me response 200, but doing from Java, I am getting this error. Does anyone have an idea about this.
Java code is as below

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
 StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(POST_CLAIM_URL);
 post.setEntity(stringEntity);
 HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
 httpResponse = client.execute(post);
```

I had make sure , I am not adding a duplicate entry.

Regards,
Varun

Comment: Do I need set Access Token in LoopBack?

Comment: Did you try using curl to see if a request outside your app works? You will need an authentication token if your endpoint is protected.

Comment: I haven't done that yet, was not much familiar with Curl. Will do some research there. Though currently I have not set any access token , so my end point is open, it should be connected with httpPost.

Comment: It worked, I saw some other post and found out that I was missing this  stringEntity.setContentType("application/json") and now I get response code 200. Now I need to research on how I can protect the protect at LoopBack and communicate with Java.

Comment: This is a know problem of the LoopBack SDK for Android, see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android/issues/54

Comment: Where this code stringEntity.setContentType("application/json") should go in?

Answer (score 0):

For authentication, see this example https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control.

As for the authentication token, you can set it in the query string of the request, like `http://localhost:3000/api/your-model?access_token=TOKEN`

Comment: Thanks, I did the same, but my findings when I set accessToken in API explorer and call http://localhost:3000/api/your-model, it works as well and the record is inserted in mongodb. I am reading the documentation for ACL, I guess that may how it will work. Feedback appreciated.